# BigVideo: How to Hide Control Options Under Video

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, html5-video, video.js

I'm currently using BigVideo.js to show my vid as a background; however, there are multiple select forms showing under my video.

They're coming from the vjs-tracksettings class, such as 'window-color vjs-tracksetting'. Not all of vjs-tracksettings needs to be turned off though, as it includes the video as well.

I have a hunch that to turn it off, I need to turn off certain Component Options (https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/guides/options.md), but I'm not sure how to do it through BigVideo. Also, my hunch is that it is within Control Bar (https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/guides/components.md).

Or it has something to do with textTrackDisplay.

Any light would help!! I've been stuck on this for awhile. 
(Also, I put all the js files in the header. I know you're supposed to put it at the end of the body tag, but for some reason, it doesn't work there.)

EDIT: I've attached a picture of what it looks like in the comments

I've attached my html here. If any css/js files are needed, let me know!

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>


  <!-- Include src files -->
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
      <script src="bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
      <script src="bower_components/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  <!-- BigVideo -->    
  <script src="bower_components/video.js/dist/video-js/video.js"></script>


      <script src="bower_components/BigVideo.js/css/bigvideo.css"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/BigVideo.js/lib/bigvideo.js"></script>



    <!-- Basic Page Needs
    –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Mobile Specific Metas
    –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    <!-- CSS
    –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css">

    <!-- Favicon
    –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- Primary Page Layout
    –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
    <div class="container">
        <div id="hello" >

          <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function() {
              var options = {
                controls: false,
                doLoop: true,
                useFlashForFirefox: false,
                poster: "initialVid.png",
              }
              var BV = new $.BigVideo(options);
              BV.init();
              BV.show([
              { type: "video/webm", src: "forest_ski.webm"},
              { type: "video/mp4", src: "forest_ski.mp4"}
              ]);
            });
          </script>
      </div>
    </div>

  <!-- End Document
    –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: http://imgur.com/woQfkLY here is a picture to help show what it looks like. the top of the picture is the bottom portion of the video

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, i've solved the issue. its because i wasnt referring to bigvideo.css as a css file. if anyone ever runs across this, that's your problem!